# Move .tex files from TeXlipse to TeXShop

Tags: errors, document-classes, texshop

I am a newbie at LaTeX/TeXlipse/TeXShop.

I am currently writing a LaTeX document using TeXlipse plugin in Ubuntu. Due to hardware issues on the Ubuntu machine I need to port the `.tex` files to TeXShop on a Mac OS X. Since I was using TeXlipse, it had created all the `.tex` files in a project format. My entry point is `document.tex`

```
\begin{document}

%include other pages
\input{./title.tex}
%\input{./certificate.tex}

\input{./abstract.tex}
\input{./acknow.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman} %numbering before main content starts
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} %reset numbering to normal for the main content

\input{./introduction.tex}
\input{./systemarchitecture.tex}
\input{./implementation.tex}
\input{./experimentresults.tex}
\input{./conclusion.tex}
\input{./ref.tex}

\end{document}
```

When I try to preview this `document.tex` file I am able to see the corresponding PDF file. But any changes made to the `introduction.tex` file are not visible. I am not sure if this is because TeXShop does not support this kind of a project structure, or do I have to include all of the data into a single `.tex` file?

The error I see in the console is as follows:

```
/introduction.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...
```

Since `introduction.tex` is not another document but the part of a bigger document should I include `\begin{document}` in every `.tex` file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You need a `\documentclass` statement and your preamble (ie, the `\usepackage{}` statements before `\begin{document}`.  When you say "changes made to the introduction.tex file are not visible" are you saying that when you recompile `document.tex` that changes from `introduction.tex` are not visible? If you do not want to compile `introduciton.tex` by itself then you don't need the `\documentclass`, premable, and `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` in `introduction.tex`.

Comment: You should also have a look at [the `standalone` package]()

Comment: @Peter Grill Oops looks like it was a beginner's error, I was compiling the introduction.tex instead of compiling document.tex , I have added the statements you mentioned earlier and it seems to be running fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In TeXShop, you can add the information of the main file (the one you're actually "compiling") using the pre-processor command:

```
% !TEX root = mainfile.tex
```

(substitute "mainfile" for whatever you're calling yours). You can also add directory indications (e.g., `./mainfile.tex`).

You should use this pre-processor command in all of your "child" documents (i.e., those which you call with `\include` or `\input` from your main file).

In the TeXShop menu, go to Macros->Root->Root, to create the command.